# rails -double negative of variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*** warning - newbie alert ***

I'm reading a book called RailsSpace to learn Ruby on Rails framework. The author built user profiles which the user can edit, and now he's building the public facing profiles based off the other user profiles. The only change he has to make is to basically hide the edit links on the public facing profile. He uses this function to hide it, but I don't understand how it works...hide_edit_links is a variable

```
 # Return true if hiding the edit links for spec, FAQ, etc. 

    def hide_edit_links?

    not @hide_edit_links.nil? 

    end
```

He also writes

> By the way, the reason hide_edit_links? works in general is that
>   instance variables are nil if not defined, so the function returns
>   false unless @hide_edit_links is set explicitly.

but I don't really get it.

Can you explain in a bit more detail for a newbie?

He implements it later with this

```
<div class="sidebar_box"> <h2>
<% unless hide_edit_links? %> <span class="edit_link">
<%= link_to "(edit)", :controller => "faq", :action => "edit" %> </span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the key to understand that code (I haven't read the book) is that `@hide_edit_links` is not a boolean, it's just some kind of tag. If `@hide_edit_links` is not `nil` ( it doesn't matter which object type it's) then hide_edit_links?` will return true.

I have to say that the code **is not at all** straight forward, it's definitely convoluted and complicated (probably without any reason)

Example 1 (New instance, without `@hide_edit_links` set, so it shows link).

- The class is instantiated (this code is not in the original question, but I assume it's there), and since there's not reference to `@hide_edit_links`, the value of the instace variable is `nil`
- When `hide_edit_links?` is invoked from the page, `@hide_edit_links` is nil, so `@hide_edit_links.nil?` returns true, and thus `not @hide_edit_links.nil?` is false.
- Since the page uses `unless hide_edit_links?`, it shows the link.

Example 2 (New instance, with `@hide_edit_links` set with an object, so it doesn't show the link).

- The class is instantiated and `@hide_edit_links` is set to a value which is not `nil`.
- When `hide_edit_links?` is invoked from the page, `@hide_edit_links` is **not** nil, so `@hide_edit_links.nil?` returns false, and thus `not @hide_edit_links.nil?` is true.
- Since the page uses `unless hide_edit_links?`, it doesn't show the link.

Sorry about the trivial examples... the 'feature' is not complicated, but the solution used by the author looks terribly complicated to my dumb brain.

Comment: I perused this book when it came out and have to agree.  This is one example of many not-so-great practices within.  Plus it's a bit out of date.  You might do better picking up the new edition of "The Rails Way" or any number of more recent books.

Comment: just to give my two cents : another syntax of double negation you can run into is `!!@variable`.
the "eloquent Ruby" book has a pretty clear explanation for this. Ruby works in a boolean context, but rarely using true booleans. This is bound to Ruby's philosophy : all is an object, and any object other than false and nil WILL be evaluated as true. So unless this @hide_edit_links is expected to explicitly become false at one point, it is nearly pointless to churn out such a convoluted code. I really recommend reading this book, it helped me a lot in understanding parts of the ruby idiom.

Comment: `!!` is often maligned for being "unreadable" and it's a good bet that the author came up with this awkward "true if not nil" construct specifically to avoid it (and in the process, ended up with code that is still awkward, and also arguably less correct).  In a more modern book he might have used `@hide_edit_links.present?` which is essentially the same as `!!@hide_edit_links`